# Inkscape: How I can organize objects in a page so they can have vertically even spacing between them

Tags: inkscape

I have three text object in my drawing. I need to have even vertical spacing between them.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Najmul Hosan, have you tried to  [align](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Align.html) them? Can you tell us something more about your efforts?

Comment: Yes I did. After selecting all of my objects, I have tried alignment, distribution, rearrange but none does the job. `AI` have got this kind of feature. Please take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8opnDkJHG8g

Answer (score 1):

Select all the text objects.

In the bar along the top click the `Align and Distribute Objects` icon

[image: Screenshot: Align and Distribute Objects]

This will call up the Align and Distribute panel.

[image: Screenshot: Align and Distribute Panel]

You can centre everything by hitting the `Centre on vertical axis` icon, or you can choose to align right or left by choosing one of the other icons.

[image: Screenshot: Centre on Vertical Axis]

You can distribute them equally by hitting the `Distribute bottom edges equidistantly` icon. Or you can choose one of the other options depending on your requirements.

[image: Screenshot: Distribute bottom edges equidistantly]

Comment: yep it does work, but I need to distribute them evenly respect to my artboard size. For example: `One` and `Three` will have equal spacing from top and bottom accordingly.

Comment: AI have got this kind of feature. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8opnDkJHG8g

Comment: Use the Relative to: "page" option. To centre the entire selection vertically choose "treat selection as group". Then hit the "centre on horizontal axis". Now use the "Distribute bottom edges".

Comment: yes I did. http://i.imgur.com/08WVWQe.png